# Server Client Communication Freezes`[Command Prompt]

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, client-server, serversocket

I am newbie to java network programming so kindly keep that in mind.

I am try to develop a multi threaded java server client application. For Starters I aim to develop a communication channel between a single client and server only. Without threading the communication between a single client-server works fine. Bu when I apply threading the program fails. The messages are not being sent.

**MyServer.java**

```
class MyServer {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        ServerSocket svc = new ServerSocket(4567);
        System.out.println("Server Waiting at Port 4567");
        do {
            Socket sock = svc.accept();
            MyServerThread thread = new MyServerThread(sock);   
        }while(true);

    }   
    catch(UnknownHostException ex) {
        System.out.println("Unknown Host");
    }
    catch(IOException ex) {
        System.out.println("IO Exception");
    }
}
}
```

**MyServerThread.java**

```
class MyServerThread extends Thread{

Socket sock;

public MyServerThread(Socket sock) {
    this.sock = sock;
}

public void run() {
    try {           
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(sock.getOutputStream());
        Scanner cd = new Scanner(sock.getInputStream());
        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);

        do {
            String clientstr = cd.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Client: "+clientstr);
            if(clientstr.equalsIgnoreCase("quit")) {
                break;          
            }
            String str = kb.nextLine();
            pw.println(str);
            pw.flush();
        }while(true);
        sock.close();
        pw.close();
    }
    catch(UnknownHostException ex) {
        System.out.println("Unknown Host");
    }
    catch(IOException ex) {
        System.out.println("IO Exception");
    }
}       
}
```

**MyClient**

```
class MyClient3 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        InetAddress object = InetAddress.getByName("192.168.18.125");
        Socket sock = new Socket(object, 4567);

        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(sock.getOutputStream());
        Scanner cd = new Scanner(sock.getInputStream());
        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);    

        do {
            String str = kb.nextLine();
            pw.println(str);
            pw.flush();
            String strserver = cd.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Server: "+strserver);
            if(strserver.equalsIgnoreCase("quit")) {
                break;
            }
        }while(true);
        sock.close();
        pw.close();
    }
    catch(UnknownHostException ex) {
        System.out.println("Unknown Host");
    }
    catch(IOException ex) {
        System.out.println("IO Exception");
    }
}
}
```

Comment: This code is not correct when you write a multi threaded client server program.When multiple clients connect to a server then it is must that you assign a id,e.g. 1,2,3,4 and so on to each client .for more details see here  [link] (http://mrbool.com/creating-a-multithreaded-chat-with-socket-in-java/34275)

Answer (score 1):

Your most immediate problem is that you don't call Thread#start() on the Thread after the creation of MyServerThread. However, usually you shouldn't create classes that extend thread. You should create a Runnable instead, and pass that to Thread#new(Runnable).